# Git: push all objects to remote repository (not just refs, but absolutely all blobs, trees and commits)

Tags: git, git-push

Context: I am (mis)using Git not for version control, but to keep a record of the relationship between files. Git's internal data structure (basically a graph of objects) has exactly what I need (cryptographic hashes, etc...) and there are plenty of very good tools to manipulate the data.

One thing I have so far not been able to do is to push the entire graph to a remote repository. As far as I understand, `git push` only acts on `refs`, not on `objects`. Is there an easy way to push all of the objects (commits, trees, blobs) to a remote or do I have to add a ref (e.g. a `branch`) on each of the commits first, then push all branches, then delete all branches (locally and on the remote)?

Comment: Would adding `--mirror` to `git push` give you what you need?

Comment: @Krzysiek Karbowiak `--mirror` only pushes refs. Even with that option, you are still not pushing dangling commits.

Comment: @calys **Unrelated heads up:** Storing dangling commits (ie. commits not reachable from any ref) is probably not a great idea. With default repo configuration, there is a risk for dangling objects to be automatically removed as a part of a cleanup procedure. This can be controlled by several different git config variables, most notably `gc.pruneExpire` (default is 2 weeks). This means that per default, any dangling commits older than 2 weeks may be removed automatically if a `git gc` is run (`git gc` can be triggered automatically).

Comment: ... Other factors might influence the period of time which needs to pass before a dangling object becomes eligible for automatic cleanup removal. E.g. if commits are referenced by the `reflog`, it will take longer time for them to expire. If you really intend to store dangling objects, you should make sure that you study all `gc` related config variables in [Git config documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

Comment: @Alderath thanks for the heads up! I am aware that dangling commits are fair game for the `gc` and that I should be careful with that. To be honest, I have not yet figured out how to solve that, and might well end up  adding a randomly named branch on each and every commit... which would solve the `git push` issue. Still, I would like to understand how to manipulate the git graph :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't, not quite.  While `git push` pushes / uploads various Git objects, it ends by setting one or more *names* in the other Git repository.  The receiving Git then tends to run `git gc` immediately afterward.

In particular, *you* run:

`git push remote refspec1 refspec2 ... refspecN`

on the command line, and your Git calls up some other Git at *`remote`* (via URL taken from `remote.remote.pushurl` for instance).  Then your Git delivers, to their Git, the objects identified by the source parts of each of your refspecs, or more precisely, offers them those objects by hash ID.  You *can* put hash IDs here:

```
git push origin a123456:name
```

The `a123456` is an abbreviated hash ID.  Whatever object that names, your Git will offer its full hash ID to the other Git.  The other Git will then check to see whether it has object `a123456`.  If so, it tells you it doesn't need the actual content; if not, your Git will package the content, and now must offer any object that `a123456` requires as well.  For instance, if `a123456` is a commit, your Git must offer its tree and parent commits; the other Git tells you whether it has them already, or needs them, which triggers yet more object-following as needed.  (There are some optimizations here to cut down on the back-and-forth communications, but the idea should be clear by this point.)

Eventually, your Git and their Git agree that if your Git sends some set of objects, they will have all the objects they need to accept (or reject!) your Git's *set some names* request.  Your Git then packages up those objects, typically as a *thin pack*, which stores those objects, but delta-compressed against objects your Git *knows or assumes* their Git already has based on the earlier have/want object-by-hash-ID conversation that led to this point.  (For instance, if you offered `a1234356` and they said they need it, then you offered its parent `a000000` and they said *ah, I already have that one*, your Git knows that they not only have object `a000000` itself, but also its tree and all of its blobs.  Moreover, if their repository is not shallow, they have all of `a000000`'s *parent* commits and all of *their* trees and blobs!  So your Git can delta-compress `a123456`'s blobs against all such earlier blobs, to make this thin pack.  It can completely omit any blobs in `a123456` that are also in `a000000`, and so on.)

Once your Git has sent the thin pack, the other side fixes it (fattens it and adds an index).  They now take your Git's set of requests of the form: *please set <name> to <hash>* (non-forced push) or the same without the *please* (forced push).  If you ran `git push origin a123456:name`, that request says *set `name` to `a123456`*.

They either obey the request/command, or reject it.  If they *reject* it, then `a123456`—which you just sent them—is pretty likely *not* reachable from any of their *other* references!  (The one case where it is, is when something else in the *same* push set or updated some *other* reference so as to make `a123456` reachable.)

When the conversation ends, after all of your *set <name> to <hash>* operations, *they* run `git gc`.  If the objects you sent them were *loose* objects, those objects would be protected by the default 14-day grace period.  But you sent them a pack file.  If they repack the pack file while incorporating the objects they're going to retain—and they almost always do that—they will *drop* any unreferenced object.

This leads to the somewhat sad conclusion that makes up the first sentence of this answer.

Comment: thanks a lot for going into such amount of detail. It makes perfect sense and means that I'll need to find a way to have all of my commits reachable by at least one reference.

Comment: jthill has a deleted answer that's quite an interesting idea: make for yourself a rather peculiar commit, using some ref name, that has as its tree, a faked-up tree with blob, subtree, and—abusing submodule types—commit references. The submodule type abuse won't work right (those don't count as references that keep commits alive, because they're links to *other* repositories' commits) but the rest would, and you could fake merge parents to make commit refs happen.

Comment: Definitely interesting but I don't understand the idea enough to actually try it out. Probably because I have never fully grasped the submodule concept... This "peculiar" commit, does it get pushed to the remote as well? Do I have to delete it from the local repository after the push?

Comment: Yes, you'd push the peculiar commit, using some name that the receiving Git will allow (receiving Gits get to set their own constraints here, though branch and tag names should always be allowed). As I said the submodule trick doesn't work anyway so you need a different trick, probably just using multiple parents, though if your actual goal is to retain file contents, you don't need to do tricky hacks with commits at all, you just need blobs—which you can save by tag names—and/or trees, which you can also save by tag names.

Comment: By "save by tag name", you mean that I would simply add a tag for each blob of the repository (which would ensure everything gets pushed)?

Comment: Yes, you could literally create one tag per blob, and then push all those tags to push the blob objects (and thus access them). This is clearly abuse of Git, but then again, if it works OK... :-) For efficiency it's probably better to make one tag pointing to one tree that contains "file names" for all the blob objects (the file names need to be unique within that tree object, but are otherwise unimportant unless you have some data that is easily encoded as a "file name").